# LOOCV in R returns error

Tags: r, r-caret

In the past days I began getting familiar with R (I come from MATLAB and Python). I wanted to try out the caret package (pretty awesome) and I keep getting the following error message when I try to train with LOOCV

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(tuneAcc, , params, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Now, at the beginning I thought "ok, I'm doing something wrong here". But then I used the code from http://machinelearningmastery.com/ :

```
library(caret)
# load the iris dataset
data(iris)
# define training control
train_control <- trainControl(method="LOOCV")
# train the model
model <- train(Species~., data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="nb")
# summarize results
print(model)
```

which returns the same error. The full code can be found at the following address http://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-estimate-model-accuracy-in-r-using-the-caret-package/ . Did I mess up my installation of R? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in the print.train function. See also [issue 435](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/435) on github. It should be fixed with the next update of caret (version 6.0-70 or higher).

Btw there is nothing wrong with the model. This you can still use to make predictions.